# Restore Install GUI with Xfce

Tags: xfce, xubuntu

I've installed Xubuntu on my laptop last night, and then again on my computer at work, and I came to notice that the Xfce desktop looks so much better on the latter. On my laptop, I get all the panels ordered the same way, but the colours are plain and the icons are very different.
I suspect it has to do with the fact that my laptop's had an xubuntu on itself once, until about 4 months ago, before I went to look at Ubuntu's Netbook Edition.
How can I get the same shiny desktop settings as I have on this fresh, virgin install?

Comment: Two screenshots to compare them would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are using the new Greybird theme:

1. From the menu choose Settings - Settings Manager.
2. Double click the Appearances Icon
3. Choose the 'greybird' style
4. icons should be "elementary xubuntu dark"
5. Fonts should be "droid sans"